# Format a double to omit unnecessary ".0" and never round off

Tags: java, string-formatting

I know how to format a double to keep only the available decimal places (DP), up to a certain number of DPs. This example keeps up to 4 DPs.

```
    double d = 1.0;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    System.out.print(df.format(d)); // returns "1"

    double d = 1.23;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    System.out.print(df.format(d)); // returns "1.23"

    double d = 1.2345678;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
    System.out.print(df.format(d)); // returns "1.2346", rounding off: bad!
```

Now I want whole numbers e.g. `1.0` to return `"1"` without the unnecessary `.0`, and the `#` format character does provide that functionality. But how do I make sure that the number never gets rounded off? Is there any other way other than an arbitrarily long chain of `#` such as `"#.###########################################"`?

Or should I just use the default conversion of double to string, and truncate the `".0"` if it appears at the end:

```
    String s = "" + d;
    if(s.substring(s.length()-2).equals(".0")) {
        s=s.substring(0, s.length()-2);
    }
```

Both ways seems terribly clumsy.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use the following

```
double d =
String s = (long) d == d ? "" + (long) d : "" + d;
```

if you need Double instead for double. (Personally I would avoid using the wrapper if you can)

```
Double d =
String s = d.longValue() == d ? "" + d.longValue() : "" + d;
```

Comment: even if the compiler may optimize it avay I believe it is better style to use String.valueOf(x) instead of "" + x

Comment: @rurouni Many would agree with you.  However, I prefer simpler code because its faster to read and write, saving you time all round.  If performance is an issue, I still wouldn't use valueOf as it creates objects.

Comment: @peter: "" + d would also call String.valueOf() internally. It will be converted to an equivalent of "new StringBuilder().append("").append(String.valueOf(d)).toString()" createing many more objects.

Comment: +1 Thanks. I just realized that I meant `Double` instead of `double`. So I guess I just have to do `(long) (double) d` instead of just `(long) d` (which doesn't compile).

Comment: @rurouni As I have found here http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/01/stringvalueofint-vs-int.html Using String.valueOf save the computer about 0.014 micro-seconds, however using `"" +` will save *you* far, far more.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I have updated my answer for `Double`

Comment: Thanks. I use the `Double` wrapper because I wanted to include these numbers in an ArrayList.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett You might like to try TDoubleArrayList http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TDoubleArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

By default the rounding mode is Up for `DecimalFormat`. You can set different rounding format as per your requiremnet using `setRoundingMode()` method

**Sample Code to set Rounding mode**

```
double d = 1.2345678;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        System.out.print(df.format(d));//result 1.2345 because of rounding down
```

Comment: "how do I make sure that the number never gets rounded"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: you cannot unless you use binary or any base 2^n number system (e.g. octal or hexadecimal)

Comment: Sure, I know about floating point arithmetic, but that's not the point of the question. How do I make sure the string representation of the number doesn't get rounded to something else than `"" + d`? This answer *explicitly* rounds it which is the exact opposite of what I asked.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Double.doubleToLongBits() and extract the exponent and mantissa. From api doc:

> Bit 63 (the bit that is selected by the mask 0x8000000000000000L)
>   represents the sign of the floating-point number. Bits 62-52 (the bits
>   that are selected by the mask 0x7ff0000000000000L) represent the
>   exponent. Bits 51-0 (the bits that are selected by the mask
>   0x000fffffffffffffL) represent the significand (sometimes called the
>   mantissa) of the floating-point number.

The exponent can be used to determine the number of significant digits, but you will always have to round at some point as some binary doulbe values will be endless in decimal.

For a binary representation you could simply use the mantissa and put the decimal dot at the right position (padding with zeros if necessary.

Comment: Most non integer decimal values cannot be represented as binary number, e.g. 0.1. so it will be approximated to 0.10000000000000000000001 or similar. Maybe you should think about how big the error of the shown representation can be (or how many significant digis are left in the previous calculation)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the question was just regarding integer numbers, but I will leave it in case someone can use it ;-)